# mongodb , how to push data to array in object?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, object

```
{
  name: "jeet",
  address: "Highway 71",
  data: {
    connnection: 2,
    frds: [
      // push here.
      {
        id: 8349,
        name: "manoj"
      },
      {
        id: 3232,
        name: "magan"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

how to add value in array that belongs to an object .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query1

- push at position 0 (start of the array)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=622b56109096ce67bc696763)

```js
update(
{"name": {"$eq": "jeet"}},
{"$push": 
 {"data.frds": {"$each": [{"id": 10, "name": "john"}], "$position": 0}}})
```

Query2

- you can do it also with update pipeline, to add on start
- puts the new element it at first of the array

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=622b46879096ce67bc696760)

```js
update(
{"name": {"$eq": "jeet"}},
[{"$set": 
   {"data.frds": 
     {"$concatArrays": [[{"id": 10, "name": "john"}], "$data.frds"]}}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $push method
[working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QYtBIIc0Lmn)

```
db.collection.update(
        { _id : ObjectId("yourid")}, //in your case use whatever is unique
        { $push: {"data.frds": {
            id:value,
            name: value2
        }}}
    )
```